# Appropriate zero variance handling for vectorised feature normalization?

Tags: matlab, statistics, octave, vectorization

**Problem:** when doing feature normalisation in Octave, zero-variance input causes div-zero errors.

**Question:** Is there a nice(r) way to handle div-zero when working with vectorised data?

**Example:** 
Input is a matrix containing multiple datasets in columns:

```
X =  [1  3.5  7.5  9 ; 
      1  4    8    9 ; 
      1  4.5  8.5  9]
```

So `X` contains three series: `x_1 = [1,1,1]`, `x_2 = [7.5, 8, 8.5]`, and `x_3 = [9,9,9]`. In order to normalise each set using vectorisation the following approach seems sensible:

```
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
X_norm = (1 ./ sigma) .* (X - mu);
```

However, the above approach will fail because both `x_1` and `x_3` have zero variance and so division-by-zero errors will occur.

My preferred handling of zero variance data is to set sigma to 1. Currently I'm using the following kludge:

```
dataset_size = length(sigma);

for index = 1:dataset_size
  if sigma(index) == 0
     sigma(index) = 1;
  endif
end
```

Notes:

- [Broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) is being used twice here, in the division and subtraction operations
- this example is based in Octave, but the question may be equally applicable to MATLAB.
- this example is simple for illustration - 'real' usage would have more, larger datasets
- this example *will* treat zero-variance data differently from regular data (imperfect by pragmatic)
- [zscore](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Statistical-Functions.html#Basic-Statistical-Functions) sounded relevant, but is (as the name suggests) better suited to calculating a z-score...

Comment: @Divakar I _think_ Octave treats `X - mu` as if a `bsxfun` was present (that's called broadcasting): `bsxfun(@minus, X, mu)`

Comment: @LuisMendo - yes, that's one of the two broadcast operations. I simultaneously love and fear those things...

Comment: Well, ideally, you would remove columns from the data set if variance = 0 since that means the values are all identical and therefore the variable contributes nothing to the model. But replacing such columns by zeros (as suggested below) is OK too.

Comment: Oh, and in addition to omitting the column, you would print out a message saying "variable <whatever> values all identical, therefore omitting this column" since it might be interesting to know which variables are contributing no information.

Comment: @Robert, in this case the aim is to normalise input data, so low variance inputs are actually very (unrealistically) good! We need to set non-zero entries to prevent div-zero errors. You're right - getting information about the problem variables would be interesting, but in this case the function is designed for speed so it's probably inappropriate to have any print statements in here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
sigma(sigma==0) = 1; %// add this line to remove zeros
X_norm = (1 ./ sigma) .* (X - mu);
```

Or, to save some operations:

```
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
ind = sigma~=0; %// detect zero values
X_norm = X - mu;
X_norm(:,ind) = X_norm(:,ind) ./ sigma(ind) ;
```

---

In general, it may be preferable to use

```
sigma(sigma<=tol) = 1; %// add this line to remove values close to zero
```

in the first approach, or

```
ind = sigma>tol; %// detect values close to zero
```

in the second, for a given tolerance `tol` (for example `tol = 1e-10`). This is a better way in applications where finite-precision errors can produce values such as `1e-15` instead of zero.

Comment: Nice! I hoped that something elegant like ```sigma(sigma==0) = 1;``` might exist. Don't expect that anyone on SO will be able to top your answer, so I'll test both approaches out tomorrow then mark as solved.

Comment: @GnomeDePlume I haven't been able to do a complete test because I don't have Octave, but if I understand broadcasting correctly it should work

Comment: Tested, and it works great. One unpaired parenthesis (I've tried to edit, but need approval for a single character change) otherwise perfect. Thanks!